# Sharing memory between two processes

Tags: c, linux

I want to share memory between two processes. One way I know is to `mmap` a shared file. However, I don't want to use a shared file, I want an anonymous mapping in the memory. How can I do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[shm_open](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/shm_unlink.3.html) is your friend. You can unmap the shared region by using [shm_unlink](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_unlink).

Answer (score 4):

Shared memory is what you want: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory

Since you're on linux, here you go: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html

Answer (score 2):

You can put your mmap'd file in the directory /dev/shm, which is mounted in most Linux systems as a tmpfs (that is, a memory-based filesystem).

Or your can mount your own tmpfs somewhere else in the directory tree (if you want other options).

Answer (score 0):

[shm_get](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget) is a good starting point, but you also need to read up about [semaphores](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semget) for mutual exclusion so that memory does not get corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that on a NUMA system, if cores are on separate nodes they will access the memory at different speeds unless you pick a NUMA node which is equidistant from the cores.