# Multiple child processes accessing the same vector

Tags: c, vector, sum, fork, child-process

I want to create a vector with 10,000 elements, set them to 5, and then create 10 child processes that do a mathematical operation on a section of that vector, and return the sum of all the elements in that section.

I'm using a vector `sums` of size 10 to store the sum of each section. But for some reason, when I print the `sums` on each child, only the element of the correspondent index has the correct value.

```c
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/wait.h>

#define VECTOR_SIZE 10000
#define INITIAL_VALUE 5
#define SECTION_SIZE 1000

int do_operations(int vetor[], int section_index);
int sum_all(int sums[]);

int main() {
    // IInitializing the vector
    int vetor[VECTOR_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; i++) {
        vetor[i] = INITIAL_VALUE;
    }

    // Doing the operations
    int sums[VECTOR_SIZE/SECTION_SIZE];
    int status;

    for(int n = 0; n < 10; n++){
        if (fork() != 0) { 
            /* Parent */
            waitpid( -1, &status, 0); 
        }
        else {
            /* Child */
            sums[n] = do_operations(vetor, n);
            printf("Sum of Section %d: %d\n", n, sums[n]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    printf("Sum of all sections: %d\n", sum_all(sums));
    return 0;
}
```

Current output:

```
Sum of Section 0: 10000
Sum of Section 1: 10000
Sum of Section 2: 10000
Sum of Section 3: 10000
Sum of Section 4: 10000
Sum of Section 5: 10000
Sum of Section 6: 10000
Sum of Section 7: 10000
Sum of Section 8: 10000
Sum of Section 9: 10000
Sum of all sections: 0
```

Expected output:

```
Sum of Section 0: 10000
Sum of Section 1: 10000
Sum of Section 2: 10000
Sum of Section 3: 10000
Sum of Section 4: 10000
Sum of Section 5: 10000
Sum of Section 6: 10000
Sum of Section 7: 10000
Sum of Section 8: 10000
Sum of Section 9: 10000
Sum of all sections: 100000
```

Comment: You do know that processes are completely separated from each other? The memory and data of one process is isolated from the memory and data of any other process. Even "sibling" processes created by the same parent. So when one process modifies the `sums` array, it does it only for its own local array. No other process, not even the parent, will know about those changes.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use threads, which share most process state (in this case, memory).

Comment: And what is even the use of independent processes here, as the code is inherently serial and not parallel (because the parent process will always `wait` before forking the next process)? The usual use-case for processes, and threads, is to allow work to be done in parallel.

Comment: So there is no way of storing the sum of each section to use after the child process ends?

Comment: Not unless you do some [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) from the children to the parent to send its own local values.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583281/sharing-memory-between-two-processes But... threads instead of processes would make things much easier...

Comment: if on linux, it should be achievable by mmaping the vector. This is hacky though, and I would recommend threads instead for an easier and more portable solution.

Comment: You can put the vector in shared memory.